# iPhoneでの動画再生

Tags: ios, iphone

ラズパイカメラで取得した動画をffmpegでエンコード生成したファイルをiPhoneで再生したいのですが、ffmpegで生成したmp4のファイルを再生することはできますか？
iPhoneはmp4形式を再生できるので、そうなるとiPhone側で再生用のアプリを作る場合デコーダーは必要でしょうか？
もし必要なのであれば、使えそうなデコーダーを教えて欲しいです。

Answer (score 1):

MPMoviePlayerViewController にファイルパスを渡すだけで QuickTime を利用して標準的な動画ファイルが再生可能です。

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *controller = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]];

[controller.moviePlayer setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeFile];

[controller.moviePlayer setRepeatMode:YES];

[controller.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];

[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:controller];
```